# How to remove Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in blogger widger.js

Tags: widget, blogger

[image]

In my blog, when I go to Google Chrome console I've found 2 errors

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () (i.e. https://www.mydomainname.com/2020/08/ortho-onother.html?action=backlinks&widgetId=Blog1&widgetType=Blog&responseType=js&postID=7891651012763992113&xssi_token=AOuZoY5Z7um4II3QJ7JP9rOsw1lNipb0HA:1598189056956&m=1
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
   I've tried lot of time to resolve this problem. Please somebody help me.

Comment: Me too, i have some error in my blogger and still find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the above error, we need to add `b:js='false'` argument in the html tag as given below signifies that the blogger should not use the static java script defined by the blogger:

```
<html b:css='false' b:js='false' >
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: Links to this post]

Toggle this checkbox as seen above